# same logic across different button IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I have many `select all` buttons within my HTML that essentially do the same thing. However they all have different ids because the buttons represent different `divs` that have different content within them. I am new to JS and I was wondering how can I perform the same logic across many `select all` buttons when one of them is clicked?

I thought about putting each `select all` button in an array containing all the ids and using

```
arr = [id1,id2,id3];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var k = document.getElementById(arr[i]);
  k.onclick = function() {//...logic...}
}
```

I'm new to JS so I'm not sure if this is a good method to approach

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: in jQuery you could use `$('#id1', '#id2', '#idn').click(function(){ alert("clicked") });` to achieve the desired result

Comment: @pbaldauf hmmm i like that. Would there be something similar in vanilla JS?

Comment: No, listening on multiple elements is something unique to jQuery. CC @pbaldauf

Comment: You maybe could use a class instead of id's so that if you're adding a button you just have to give the same class for it to be handled. As you will probably have the same look for it, it will also be of use in your css. There is a getElementByClassName() method available in vanilla js. You just need to check for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code should work. Just make sure that in the array of IDs, they are proper strings (put quotes around them). Also, if you plan on doing something with `i` inside the click callback, please read [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)